# Solr Error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: solr, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I an using dse4.6 with one solr and one cassandra node.it was working fine but suddenly i am start getting the below error in solr and in system.log:

ERROR [MutationStage:58] 2015-04-22 02:47:16,723 CassandraDaemon.java (line 199) Exception in thread Thread[MutationStage:58,5,main]
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.Cql3SolrSecondaryIndex.addClusteringColumns(Cql3SolrSecondaryIndex.java:326)
        at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.Cql3SolrSecondaryIndex.buildIndexedColumnFamily(Cql3SolrSecondaryIndex.java:157)
        at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.doApplyUpdates(AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:935)
        at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.index(AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:148)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.index.SecondaryIndexManager$StandardUpdater.updateRowLevelIndexes(SecondaryIndexManager.java:657)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.AtomicSortedColumns.addAllWithSizeDelta(AtomicSortedColumns.java:208)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable.resolve(Memtable.java:218)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable.put(Memtable.java:165)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.apply(ColumnFamilyStore.java:901)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.apply(Keyspace.java:371)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.apply(Keyspace.java:336)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.RowMutation.apply(RowMutation.java:211)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.RowMutationVerbHandler.doVerb(RowMutationVerbHandler.java:56)
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessageDeliveryTask.run(MessageDeliveryTask.java:62)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Any one have any idea,why i am geting this error?

Thnaks in advance..

Comment: What minor version of DSE 4.6 are you using?

Comment: Can you show what happened in your logs before the Exception? It might be an OOM like https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8065

Comment: I have added the log before exception.please have a look.thanks

Comment: @phact we're using the latest 4.6.5 of DSE and facing currently the same issue on one of our clusters